# Let $E$ contain only the atoms $P_1,…,P_n$, and $E^*$ come from $E$ by substituting $A_1,…,A_n$ for $P_1,…,P_n$. If $E$ is valid, so is $E^*$.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Theorem 1. (Substitution for atoms.) Let $E$ be a formula containing only the atoms  $P_{1},…,P_{n}$, and let $E^{*}$ come from $E$ by substituting formulas $A_{1},…,A_{n}$ simultaneously for $P_{1},…,P_{n}$, respectively. If $E$ is valid, then $E^{*}$ is valid.

Some context:
We say formulas (which are declarative sentences) are either prime (atoms) or composite (molecules). We’re not concerned with the internal structure of the atoms, just that we can identify them. Atoms can be made into molecules by the use of five propositional connectives. The one of the five I used in the proof below is the equivalence symbol, $\sim$. Finally, we say a formula is valid (or a tautology) if its truth table only consists of true in the truth value column; we assume that each atom is either true or false but not both.

---

Proof. Let us suppose $E$ is valid, that is, its truth table consists of all t’s in the truth value column, regardless of whether each $P_{i}$, for $i = 1,…,n$, is true or false. We let $E^{*}$ come from $E$ by substituting formulas $A_{1},…,A_{n}$ simultaneously for $P_{1},…,P_{n}$, respectively. Thus, $A_{i} \sim P_{i}$ for $i =1,…,n$. By this equivalence, $E^{*}$ is valid.

Have I proven this theorem? The proof isn’t provided in the text, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun “Mathematical Logic” by Stephen Cole Kleene.

Comment: No, you haven't proven it. The relations $A_i\sim P_i$ is not established (whatever $\sim$ means), and I guess it's not even true.

Comment: @Berci Let $A$ and $B$ be formulas. If $A$ is true and $B$ is true, then $A\simB$ is true; if $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $A\simB$ is false; if $A$ is false and $B$ is true, then $A\simB$ is false; if $A$ is false and $B$ is false, then $A\simB$ is true. This definition was established before the Theorem.

Comment: $A_i$ might be independent of $P_i$ (doesn't include it), then we never get $P_i\sim A_i$: we can take different evaluations of the atoms. If *at one evaluation* they have the same truth value, modifying the evaluation at $P_i$ will make them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is not working, because we can't have $P_i\sim A_i$ in general (see my comments).

Instead, assume a truth value assignment $\varphi$ is given for all the atoms. This induces a truth assignment for the formulas $A_i$. Now if we take an assignment $\psi$ where $P_i$ has these values ($\psi(P_i)=\varphi(A_i)$), we get the truth value of $E^*$ under $\varphi$ as the truth value of $E$ under $\psi$, which is assumed to be $true$.

Since $\varphi$ was arbitrary, this proves the validity of $E^*$.

Comment: Thank you wholeheartedly. I understand your approach, but I don’t understand your comment on why $A_{i}$ might be independent of $P_{i}$. Doesn’t substitution alleviate the issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Actually, $P_i,\ A_i,\ (P_i\sim A_i)$ are all *formulas*. And they all are evaluated either true or false *whenever a truth assignment is given*, but it can vary. I'm quite sure that your solution idea is the same as mine but handled the wrong weapon to put it in words.

Comment: I think so too. I never justified why $A_i$ should have the same truth table as $P_i$.

Comment: The atoms of the original formula E need not have any variables in common with the substituting formulas A$_1$, ..., A$_n$.  Thus, a truth value assignment for all of the atoms need not induce anything for the formulas A$_i$.

Answer (score 0):

I think Kleene proved this in Introduction to Metamathematics.

The key parts lies in that the original formula holds for all truth values of the variables, and that the substitution has to get applied consistently.  Thus, the overall truth value of the tautology doesn't get changed by substitution, since the relationship of truth values among the subformulas remains constant.